# Yocto rebuild is not overwriting

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I made some changes on u-boot source `/tmp/work/beaglebone_my-poky-linux-gnueabi/u-boot/1_2018.07-r0/git`

When I rebuild with bitbake core-image-minimal. Bitbake is not overwriting images in the path `/images/`.

Then I used clean, cleansstate, but both of them deleted all my changes in the `u-boot/1_2018.07-r0/git` directory.

What is the most efficient way to customize the u-boot and kernel?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Changing a recipe's fetched sources directory is not enough to permanently modify source code in Yocto as it is just a temporary working directory that, as you experienced, can be cleaned and all.

Changes to Yocto recipes sources can be made by:

1. modifying the source code in the working directory
2. creating a patch for your changes
3. change/create some recipe to apply your patch
4. the patch will be applied in build time

This section describes the process of modifying source code and creating a patch:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6.1/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#modifying-source-code

This section describes the process of creating an extra layer and a recipe for the patches you created in order to apply them during build time:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6.1/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html#modifying-source-code

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i am reading the document you sent. It says, i should use the commands;
       bitbake linux-yocto -c compile -f 
       bitbake linux-yocto -c deploy
can i also  use "bitbake my-image" instead of the commands above to rebuild the kernel?

Comment: That won't work for the case of modifying the sources in their working directory as bitbake won't see any need to rerun the compile task. That's why you specifically have to force it reran using the -f flag.

Comment: thank you. "bitbake -f my-image" also would not work?

Comment: These commands on the document is to rebuild kernel, do you know
which command should i use, if i want to rebuild .dtb file again,
which command should i use if i want to rebuild other packages, everything includes bsp.

Answer (score 0):

use this;

bitbake -c compile -f TARGET_PKG

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).